# websocket server and client using WebsocketSharp on localhost

Tags: c#, websocket-sharp

I am trying to write a simple client-server application using WebsocketSharp on the same device (localhost) but I keep getting a "Not a Websocket handshake response.

the client is set up like so:

```
private const int _port = 555;
 private static WebSocket _ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + IPAddress.Loopback.ToString() + $":{_port}/websocket" );
```

also tried with / WebSocket

the server is set up like so

```
private const int _port = 555;
        private static  WebSocketServer _ws = new WebSocketServer(IPAddress.Loopback, _port);
```

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you add the service ... this is 8 months old BUT Im not sure if you figured this out or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).